# How to create pyspark dataframe with CharType column?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, char

I'm trying to create a dataframe with "rich" column data types in pyspark (Spark version 3.4.0):

```py
from datetime import date
from decimal import Decimal
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import *

data = [
  (1, 'abc', Decimal(3.142), date(2023, 1, 1)),
  (2, 'bcd', Decimal(1.414), date(2023, 1, 2)),
  (3, 'cde', Decimal(2.718), date(2023, 1, 3))]

schema = StructType([
  StructField('INT', IntegerType()),
  StructField('STR', CharType(3)),
  StructField('DEC', DecimalType(4, 3)),
  StructField('DAT', DateType())])

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('data-types').getOrCreate()
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)
df.show()
```

When I run this I get

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: [BUG] logical plan should not have output of char/varchar type: LogicalRDD [INT#0, STR#1, DEC#2, DAT#3], false
```

The same happens with `VarcharType(3)`, with `StringType()` for the `STR` column it works. Since I'm working on a system where I need to retain as much type information from the data source as possible I would much prefer to be able to use `CharType()` and `VarcharType()` with string length specification.

How can I get this to work?

PS:
I tried to work around the exception by using `StringType()` in the schema and then doing

```py
df.withColumn('STR', col('STR').cast(CharType(3)))
```

That got me a

```
WARN CharVarcharUtils: The Spark cast operator does not support char/varchar type and simply treats them as string type.
```

So now I'm wondering whether `CharType()` is supported as column data type at all... The [latest documentation of the data type](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.types.CharType.html#pyspark.sql.types.CharType) does not mentioned any such restriction.

Comment: Were you able to figure out answer for this?

Comment: No, unfortunately not, but due to shifts in priorities this issue got backburnered...